# How to repair a file system corruption?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, data-recovery, ext4

Debian on external USB SSD drive. There was some error in `dmesg` log file:

```
...[    3.320718] EXT4-fs (sdb2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    3.320721] EXT4-fs (sdb2): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    5.366367] EXT4-fs (sdb2): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[    5.366375] EXT4-fs (sdb2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 6072
[    5.366426] EXT4-fs (sdb2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 6071
[    5.366442] EXT4-fs (sdb2): 2 orphan inodes deleted
[    5.366444] EXT4-fs (sdb2): recovery complete
...
```

The system boots and works normally. Is it possible to repair this fully, and what is the proper way?

Comment: If this happens after a brutal shutdown, no worries, it s probably tmp files. If it happened during use, then you should first backup everything important (on 2 separate supports, in case one fails)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can instruct the filesystem to perform an immediate `fsck` upon being mounted like so:

#### Method #1: Using /forcefsck

You can usually schedule a check at the next reboot like so:

```
$ sudo touch /forcefsck
$ sudo reboot
```

#### Method #2: Using shutdown

You can also tell the `shutdown` command to do so as well, via the `-F` switch:

```
$ sudo shutdown -rF now
```

**NOTE:** The first method is the most universal way to achieve this!

#### Method #3: Using tune2fs

You can also make use of `tune2fs`, which can set the parameters on the filesystem itself to force a check the next time a mount is attempted.

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
Mount count: 3
Maximum mount count: 25
```

So you have to place the "Mount count" higher than 25 with the following command:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -C 26 /dev/sda1
```

Check the value changed with `tune2fs -l` and then reboot!

**NOTE:** Of the 3 options I'd use `tune2fs` given it can deal with force checking any filesystem whether it's the primary's (`/`) or some other.

#### Additional notes

You'll  typically see the "Maximum mount count:" and "check interval:" parameters associated with a partition that's been formatted as ext2/3/4. Often times they're configured like so:

```
$ tune2fs -l /dev/sda5 | grep -E "Mount count|Maximum mount|interval"
Mount count:              178
Maximum mount count:      -1
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
```

When the parameters are set this way, the device will never perform an `fsck` during mounting. This is fairly typical with most distros.

There are 2 forces that drive a check. Either number of mounts or an elapse time. The "Check interval" is the time based one. You can say every 2 weeks to that argument, 2w. See the `tune2fs` man page for more info.

**NOTE:** Also make sure to understand that `tune2fs` is a filesystem command, not a device command. So it doesn't work with just any old device, `/dev/sda`, unless there's an ext2/3/4 filesystem there, the command `tune2fs` is meaningless, it has to be used against a partition that's been formatted with one of those types of filessystems.

#### References

- [Linux Force fsck on the Next Reboot or Boot Sequence](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-force-fsck-on-the-next-reboot-or-boot-sequence/)

Comment: the first two methods are one-time operations, and #3 allows set this operation permanently?

Comment: Yeah it's set permanently, you generally need to go back and reset them after you're done with the `fsck`. At least that's what I do anyways.

Comment: I have `Mount count: 21`
`Maximum mount count: -1`
`Check interval:0 (<none>)` It's not clear, what setting to specify?

Comment: The "Max mnt cnt: -1" and "check interval: 0" are blocking any checks from ever occurring. make "Max mnt cnt" set to 20 and "check interval" can stay 0. There are 2 forces that drive a check. Either number of mounts or an elapse time. The 2nd argument is the time based one. You can say every 2 weeks to that argument, `2w`. See the `tune2fs` man page for more info.

Comment: these setting are used for partitions only, or can be for disk `/dev/sdb`?

Comment: @triwo - partitions, not HDDs. `tune2fs` is setting parameters for a filesystem (EXT2/3/4) that you've formatted them with.

Comment: @triwo - see updates to A, hopefully they help.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to perform a `fsck` unmount this partition `/dev/sdb2` **if you have nothing important riding on that device**, if that does not work try doing a fsck with a live CD.

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb2
```

Comment: I already ran `fsck -n -f` check, it show no errors.

Comment: problems and brings you this?

Comment: no problem while installation is still fresh, but I want to avoid an unexpected problems in the future. Was the file system completely fixed during recovery?

Comment: That will depend on the status of the disk physically, checking typically linux hdd automates every any given time, so it can also be a chore, however you must be careful .

I recommend you to run a fsck to dismount the partition at the time this is not writing or reading any device access as long as this is not the file system of your

Comment: I mean if log show recovery complete and fsck show no error,  the system is fixed competely? The ssd drive is almost new.

Answer (score 0):

Believe you are requiring to run a fsck kind of operation. You can try running `fsck` as follows:

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb2
```